# What worklists should CADx system use when General Purpose & Unified Worklists are not implemented

Tags: dicom

I want to integrate an AI Diagnostic tool into various hospital workflows.  The Integrating Healthcare Enterprise (IHE) define two workflows for this:

- `Post Processing Workflow`, using the (now retired) `DICOM General Purpose Worklist`
- `AI Workflow`, using the new `DICOM Unified Worklist`.

However, most PACS vendors implement neither of these (Change Health Radiology Solutions, FujiFilm Synapse, IBM Merge - I am looking at you).  They only implement the Modality Worklist from a DICOM perspective, plus it seems some proprietary workflow tools.

So the question: what does everyone else do?  Do they:

1. Pretend to be a Modality and just use the `Modality Worklist` / `Modality Procedure Steps`.
2. Try to integrate with each vendor's custom solution
3. Abandon the whole worklist exercise and just poll for new images (perhaps using the `Instance Availability Notification`?).

There seems to be a surprising disconnect between what is recommended by the IHE and what is implemented by the various PACS vendors.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions about software and procedural systems used in medicine aren't exactly on topic as described in [What topics can I ask about here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This site is more about clinical medicine and less about administration. But it's not totally out of bounds so I'll leave it open to see if you can catch a decent answer, but I don't hold high hopes.